# Binary Encounter Bethe model: Why does it overestimate ionisation cross-sections SF6, even though generally it underestimates them for other species

Tags: scattering

I was reading a paper online that can be found [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/5.0039465).

In the paper they claim that BEB (binary encounter bethe) AE and ECP (all-electrons and effective core potential) will typically underestimate the ionisation cross section when compared with experimental data. They justify this as follows:

> "It should be noted that a disadvantage of using an ECP is that all
> the inner shell orbitals are removed. These orbitals may contribute
> little to the BEB cross section at low energies; however, the high
> energy tail of an ECP calculated BEB cross section can be expected to
> be underestimated as a result of the missing core ionization."

However I have done some calculations for SF6 and some other flourinated hydrocarbons and in these handful of examples we see that actually the theoretical BEB model overestimates the ionisation cross section when compared with experimentel data.

My question is whether anybody can think of a reason/explanation as to why the BEB model will overestimate the ionisation cross sections for $SF_6$ and some florinated carbons.

If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it because currently it is confusing me.

I have attached the following data from NIST to illustrate my point of how BEB overestimates the ionisation cross section for $SF_6$

[image]

Comment: DJA, how has this been going for you? Since it's been almost 5 months without an answer, I wonder if you have any update you could give us?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to give an answer.